# aws lambda to create different init script on different ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function to launch windows EC2 instance with below user data and gather instance details from environment variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import boto3

AMI = os.environ["AMI"]
INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ["INSTANCE_TYPE"]
KEY_NAME = os.environ["KEY_NAME"]
SUBNET_ID = os.environ["SUBNET_ID"]
REGION = os.environ["REGION"]
ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
init_script = '''<powershell>$USERNAME="latchu"
$PASSWORD="eM2An@ydxk"
net user /add $USERNAME $PASSWORD</powershell>'''
instance = ec2.run_instances(
    ImageId=AMI,
    InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
    KeyName=KEY_NAME,
    SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
    MaxCount=3,
    MinCount=1,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior="terminate",
    UserData=init_script,
)
```

Here, i have used simple init script to create one user with password on Windows Instance. But its very easy when i go with launch one instance. Some times, I should create more than 100 instance with different userdata which is creating user.
I can simply create more than 100 instance using MaxCount in boto3.

```
MaxCount=3
```

However, my case each Ec2 instance should have separate user credentials.

So i would like to one lambda function to handle more than 100 instances with different userdata. How can i achieve ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but its not clear. Where are those 100 credentials coming from? You want start 100 lambda functions, one for each set of credentials, or you want to use one lambda function to start all 100 instances?

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. Yes, i want to use one lambda function to launch all 100 instance. As well i don't have way to bring 100 user credentials. Can you please advice on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "user credentials"? Are you saying that the part of your script that runs `net user /add` should supply different credentials each time Yes, that will be a problem since you are wanting the same User Data script to run on _every_ instance. I would recommend either using Active Directory (instead of individual users), or launching each instance separately.

Comment: Yes, It will new user and password by net user command, which is part of my script. My complete script will create user then user profile and finally copy reg from template user to newly created user.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two different ways to achieve this.Either creating the user during bootstrap as you so, or doing it post-boot once the instance is up and running.

1. If you want to stick to the first approach rather than using `MaxCount` and hardcoding the credentials in the init-script within the lambda handler you need to fully templatize it and in addition use a for loop and iterate over something. Now, based on where you want to have the same username but with a different password on those 100 instances:

- you can create function that will simply create 100 different password by generating a random script. In order to not lose those credentials another function could store them encrypted in [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html).
- A slightly different approach would be to have a csv or a json file with your credentials pre-generated on which you can loop over and read them line by line in order to pass them as vars to the init-script. You'll need to make sure that file is stored securily somewhere.

2. Rather than creating the user in the init-script you can do it once the instance is up. Here, you can rely on multitude of AWS Services based on your preference (like OpsWorks for example), but [I would recommend Systems Manager and more specifically the RunCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html) which you can use to run a PowerShell script to create the user locally on the instance. Here you would need a trigger for the RunCommand.

- One option is to wait for the instance to be available and directly call the RunCommand command in your current lambda, but this is going to be sub-optimal as it will prove to be costly and you will most likely hit the 15-minute lambda limit
- [A slightly better approach would be to watch for the Instance Creation event which will then trigger the RunCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/automating_with_eventbridge.html)
- Third option would be to start the RunCommand against all instances with a certain Tag (e.g. PostInstallUserCreation)

You'll still need to create or pass the credentials somehow in this second post-bootstrap approach and in general you can use a mixture between the two options and either generate random strings to pass to the RunCommand (or even generate them locally on the instance within the powershell script) or poll for credential pre-created and stored in Parameter Store or Secrets Manager.

3. As suggested by John in the comments rather than creating local users you can go for Active Directory
4. You can scrap credentials all together and use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) or even potentially tool like HashiCorp Boundary or similar.

Comment: Yes, I should go with Active Directory for user management.